# When action takes place, how does swift updates screen?

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and just curious about how swift updates screen.
What I mean by this is that when we click button or activate some function, how does it load the result into screen?

For ex)
if I push the button which changed the background color, does swift reload entire screen output? Or does it just dynamically update the specific feature that changed by the preceding action?

Sorry for vague question...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

This is a very broad question. Your second intuition about how the screen is updated is correct, but the mechanism that updates only the part of the screen that needs to be updated isn't Swift itself -- it's the underlying libraries contained in iOS that handle these events and other lower-level events and concerns.

The highest level library on iOS is called Cocoa Touch. It is similar to Cocoa on Mac OS X, or any other high-level library on any other operating system. The critical point is that Cocoa Touch is the main API (Application Programming Interface) for iOS. It allows you to interact with the top-level system services. The Cocoa Touch API can be used by C, Objective-C, and Swift, so when you write Swift code that responds to a button press, your Swift code is being called by the Cocoa Touch APIs that expose the built-in system controls. Those controls are in turn drawn by another library called Core Graphics. There are many layers to the operating system onion, and they are all extremely interesting in their own right.

You may want to have a look at some broader perspectives on programming and how code is translated into the actions you see on a screen. Definitely get your hands dirty and have fun, but your initial question is fundamental to all modern GUI programming, and an introductory text on Operating Systems will be very helpful.

Note that it doesn't need to be a book about the iOS operating system. Even better, learn some basics about Unix, Linux, or any *nix-style OS because iOS is based on a variant of *nix systems, and you'll run into them all the time.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. I think I have to play around more with Swift, and read about its related documents and whatever. Though, thank you for answering me XD

Comment: To be more specific, only the changed component is redrawn. The screen refreshes 60 times per second, but the system keeps a copy of it in memory and modifies it only when necessary. Also, if you're satisfied with the given answer, mark it as correct and any further questions you ask on StackOverfow are more likely to be answered :)